# Why must the XHR status be set before echoes in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Perhaps this question belongs on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or another site instead, in which case please tell me and don't just downvote; I will gladly move it.

Anyway, I'm just learning the very basics of server management and I was playing around with my own small, private MySQL server on my laptop when I happened upon something I hadn't expected. When I sent an AJAX request to a PHP page using the jQuery [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method, I was continuing to get the response code of "200" even though I called the function [`http_response_code(500);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) in my PHP code. I couldn't figure out why this was happening until I realized that I was using `echo` statements to return data to the Javascript page, and by moving the `http_response_code(500);` function to *above* all of the `echo` statements, it would set the HTTP response code correctly.

**I understand this is correct functionality, I am just wondering why this is the case?** Why must the HTTP response code be set before using echo functions? What's happening in the underlying protocols? My guess is that it has something to do with `echo` forcing the script to return data when it is called, but then why do scripts like the following:

```
echo "thing one";
echo "thing two";
http_response_code(500);
echo "thing three";
```

...still echo "thing three" just fine but don't change the response code?

I'm not having a "problem" per se, I'm just here to learn! Thanks!

Comment: Please let me know if there is anything unclear or that needs to be edited about the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you print anything on the body, headers must be already sent. That's if you e.g. `echo()` something or even if there's a space before the `<?php`. A web server simply can't output anything before it has sent the headers, as that's the form of a HTTP response, causing any output to send the headers, too.

If you try to use e.g. [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) that sends a header, you could get a `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by`.

> Remember that `header()` must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with `include`, or `require`,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before `header()` is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Because [`http_response_code()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) does not send HTTP headers, but only prepares the header list to be sent later on, it won't trigger this error. While using [`headers_sent()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) in an `if` condition can prevent these errors with `header()`, it could also be useful for debugging issues when using `http_response_code()`.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense! So when the client-side script checks for the headers, does it only do it once? E.g. if I send an echo statement that keeps the default status of '200', and then later change the status with "http_response_code()" and then send another echo statement, will the client only see the original '200' code and not any of the others after it?

Comment: It's in HTTP headers. All the headers are sent before anything else, and you can't send additional headers once you have already start sending the body. Also, it's the status code: it's on the first line of a HTTP response and there can be only one first line and, thus, one response code.